# Zeoslib: How to tell if query is still processing?

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, zeos

I am using Zeoslib in Delphi to access a local MySQL database.

I call a stored procedure with the TZQuery object:

```
ZMakeRankedTable.SQL.Text :=
  'CALL MakeRankedTable(:tableA,:tableB,:SAMP_startTime,:SAMP_endTime,:Hourspan)';
```

This stored procedure ends up filling a MySQL table with values.

I need to access these values, but I have no idea when MySQL is finished processing the query.
I end up accessing the table before processing is complete.

Is there a `.IsAvailable` or `.IsExecuting` property I can access to determine whether my query has completed? If not, then how can I do it?

Comment: Can you send more info, code fragments would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no property available that indicates that your query is still running. But when the ZMakeRankedTable.Execute command terminates mysql should be ready processing the stored procedure.
So I see only 3 situations where you can access the mysql table while the procedure results are not available yet.

- You query from a parallel thread
- You're querying from another connection, but the transaction of the
  'stored proc connection' isn't finished (no autocommit nor commit
  happened)
- Your stored proc launches a delayed process and returns
  immediately. Which is unlikely, as you need to do quite some work to
  have that effect in mysql.

mdaems

Project Admin Zeoslib

Comment: Well, it should have a .IsAvailable or .IsExecuting property. Actually it should have a OnProcessing event so we could put a percentage or animation in the main thread user vcl. ;-)